# Google Cloud Functions - Local Emulator not accepting parameters

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a very basic HTTP Function:

```
exports.reporting = functions.https.onRequest(async (req,res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const text = req.query.text;
        console.log(text);
        return res.send(`Test Completed`);
    });
});
```

When I call: `curl "http://localhost:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/reporting"`

It works fine:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : Test Completed
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    vary: Origin
                    connection: close
                    Content-Length: 14
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2021 06:51:07 GMT
                    ETag: W/"e-NPX2Kiy1JwL0pK33NZe7NuviU84"
                    X-Powered-By...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[vary, Origin], [connection, close], [Content-Length, 14], [Content-Type, text/html;
                    charset=utf-8]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 14
```

But when I call: `curl "http://localhost:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/reporting?text=abc123"`

I get an error:

```
curl : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl "http://localhost:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/reporting?text=abc123"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The Emulator log shows the function times out?

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "reporting"
!  functions: Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
>  C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:640
>              throw new Error("Function timed out.");
>              ^
>
>  Error: Function timed out.
>      at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:640:19)
>      at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
>      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
>      at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
>      at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Worth to mention the deployed function works fine with parameters.

Comment: Could you try testing your curl command like this: `curl "http://localhost:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/reporting/?text=abc123"`. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1314) depending on the version of the emulator you are using. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Wow, that worked. On Windows firebase-tools 9.2.1

Comment: I'm glad that my comment helped you. Posting answer for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing Firebase Functions that use a query string on the URL on the Emulator with the curl tool don't forget to add the slash '/' prior the query string (denoted by the question mark symbol '?') in a similar fashion to: `http://localhost:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/reporting/?text=abc123`.